# Outlook Connector not working anymore in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, connector, hotmail

My mother has been using the Outlook connector for her Hotmail account in Outlook 2007.  It stopped working two weeks ago and she was not able to receive any emails from Hotmail in Outlook.  I have tried everything and feel it's not a fault on our side.  I have connected to her Hotmail account via web browser and there is no problem there.  It looks like she is now on Outlook.com.   I see there has been server changes but not sure what to do here.

My mother wants to continue using Outlook 2007 to receive her Hotmail/Outlook. com emails.  What can I do?  Can I set up a new account within Outlook 2007 and have her continue to receive emails from Outlook.com which she is familiar with?

Outlook Connector Error messages she receives are as follows:
Error in Mail
There is an error synchronizing your mail account. Please verify your account is configured correctly by first accessing your mail on the web.
Error: 3219. Server. An error occurred in looking up the user's information in mserv.

Any help would be most appreciated in this matter.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and corrected it.  You no longer need Outlook Connector to use Outlook with your hotmail account.  If hotmail is the only email account used on outlook, save all email, contacts, etc. to a "PST" data file and remove the existing hotmail accoount from outlook.  Then set up a new email account using the Microsoft Exchange option.  Note that I have Windows Vista and actually was dierected in Outlook to set up the new email account in Control Panel / Mail funtion.  I closed Outlook, and went to the Control Panel / Mail funtion and set up the Microsoft Exchange email account.  All the settings were set up automatically so all I you need to know is your hotmail email address and password for the email account.  After you reboot and start Outlook, you open the PST file to access your old emails.